# Combineable coupon codes

Tags: coupon-codes

How to create a coupon code that can be combined with other coupon codes?
I have a coupon code called '10dollars', it will take off a flat $10 from the cart.
It is an incentive for creating an account but it has to be able to be combined with other site wide coupon codes.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you manage to get the issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box Magento only supports one coupon code per order and there's not really a quick fix to implement this.

There are several paid extensions you can use for this such as *Amasty Multi coupon* and *Unirgy Giftcert*. I haven't used them but both extension developers generally have reliable extensions and offer support